# Convert a data.frame into a MediaWiki table

Tags: r, dataframe, mediawiki, pandoc

I know the functions `xtable` and `print.xtable` can convert a data.frame into html or latex code. Is there a way to convert it to a MediaWiki table?

Comment: You could go the route [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/) + [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). There might be a more direct way.

Comment: What's the appropriate wiki markup (there are many different formats)? Easiest strategy might be to output to one of the supported xtable formats and then use pandoc to convert.

Comment: @Thomas how can I find this out? I am using the default mediawiki

Comment: To the people who silently voted to close this question: why that? A comment would be welcome.

Comment: The question seems to ask for a tool or software to accomplish a task. There isn't a reproducible example or an expected output. It's an interesting question, but didn't seem to fit the bill for an SO question.

Comment: @BenBarnes it is not clear. I am not asking for a tool, just for a way to do it programatically (and I was thinking to try to do that in R, as I made a reference to 2 R functions). Now if the answers to this question suggest external tools, it is not a reason to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `kable` function from knitr to create a markdown representation and then do a system call to pandoc to create the MediaWiki table:

```
library("knitr")
cat(kable(mtcars), file = "mtcars.md", sep = "\n")
system("pandoc -t mediawiki -o mtcars.txt mtcars.md")
```

The `mtcars.md` file will look like:

```
|                    |  mpg| cyl|  disp|  hp| drat|    wt|  qsec| vs| am| gear| carb|
|:-------------------|----:|---:|-----:|---:|----:|-----:|-----:|--:|--:|----:|----:|
|Mazda RX4           | 21.0|   6| 160.0| 110| 3.90| 2.620| 16.46|  0|  1|    4|    4|
|Mazda RX4 Wag       | 21.0|   6| 160.0| 110| 3.90| 2.875| 17.02|  0|  1|    4|    4|
|Datsun 710          | 22.8|   4| 108.0|  93| 3.85| 2.320| 18.61|  1|  1|    4|    1|
|Hornet 4 Drive      | 21.4|   6| 258.0| 110| 3.08| 3.215| 19.44|  1|  0|    3|    1|
|Hornet Sportabout   | 18.7|   8| 360.0| 175| 3.15| 3.440| 17.02|  0|  0|    3|    2|
|Valiant             | 18.1|   6| 225.0| 105| 2.76| 3.460| 20.22|  1|  0|    3|    1|
|Duster 360          | 14.3|   8| 360.0| 245| 3.21| 3.570| 15.84|  0|  0|    3|    4|
...
```

pandoc will convert his to a MediaWiki representation:

```
{|
!
!align="right"|mpg
!align="right"|cyl
!align="right"|disp
!align="right"|hp
!align="right"|drat
!align="right"|wt
!align="right"|qsec
!align="right"|vs
!align="right"|am
!align="right"|gear
!align="right"|carb
|-
|Mazda RX4
|align="right"|21.0
|align="right"|6
|align="right"|160.0
|align="right"|110
|align="right"|3.90
|align="right"|2.620
|align="right"|16.46
|align="right"|0
|align="right"|1
|align="right"|4
|align="right"|4
|-
...
```

And the result after running through MediaWiki looks correct:

[image]

Comment: I have tried using pandoc 1.9.1.1 : file 'mtcars.md' is the same as yours. But file 'mtcars.txt' doesn't contain mediawiki code, but something similar to 'mtcars.md' (but only on one line). Is there something I need to configurate in pandoc ?

Comment: and I confirm I an using argument `-t mediawiki`

Comment: @RockScience This was done using pandoc 1.13.2. Consider updating and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you I have used the latest source from pandoc and it works great.

Comment: I am facing an issue because of of my cell contains the dollar sign `$`. Pandoc is converting automatically this into a `<math>`. I have browsed the options of pandoc but cannot find anything to prevent this. Have you had the same issue?

Comment: EDIT: added new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553312/prevent-pandoc-from-converting-into-math)

Comment: Post this as a new question. You can refer back to this one in your new question.