# prevent pandoc from converting $ into mediawiki <math>

Tags: markdown, mediawiki, r-markdown, pandoc

I am converting a markdown file into mediawiki table using pandoc:

content of file `mtcars.md`:

```
|   |c1   |c2 |
|:--|:----|:--|
|7  |P$A |A  |
|8  |AB  |B  |
|9  |P$A |C  |
```

Then I do (I am using Ubuntu 64 bits and pandoc version 1.13.2)

```
pandoc -t mediawiki -o mtcars.txt mtcars.md
```

But the two `$` signs are interpreted as `<math>...</math>`:

```
{|
!
!c1
!c2
|-
|7
|P<math>A |A | |8 |AB |B | |9 |P</math>A
|C
|}
```

How can I get the dollar signs instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [pandoc documentation](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) says:

> Anything between two $ characters will be treated as TeX math. The
>   opening $ must have a non-space character immediately to its right,
>   while the closing $ must have a non-space character immediately to its
>   left, and must not be followed immediately by a digit. Thus, $20,000
>   and $30,000 won’t parse as math. If for some reason you need to
>   enclose text in literal $ characters, backslash-escape them and they
>   won’t be treated as math delimiters.

So, one way is to put a backslash in front of the $:

```
|   |c1   |c2 |
|:--|:----|:--|
|7  |P\$A |A  |
|8  |AB  |B  |
|9  |P\$A |C  |
```

Output:

```
| |c1 |c2 | |:--|:----|:--| |7 |P$A |A | |8 |AB |B | |9 |P$A |C |
```

(I don't seem to get the same mediawiki output formatting as you, but you get the point).

Another way is to put a space after the $, although that adds a space in the output.

The interpretation of the $ signs are part of a markdown extension called `tex_math_dollars` - you should be able to suppress that altogether by specifying an input format of `markdown-tex_math_dollars` or `markdown_strict` (although that did not work on the older version of pandoc that I have here).

Comment: Thank you that works. Regarding the wiki formatting that's because we are not using the same version of pandoc

Comment: There are a better solution? `markdown_strict` is so strict!  See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4566